# Counting zero b-bit subsequences in a byte array

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I am looking for the fastest way of counting the number of **b**-bit subsequences (non-overlapping) that are **zero** in an `uint8_t` array of arbitrary size **S** (**S** is usually small though).

Constraints:

- **b** is always a power of two, valid values are actually only: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and 32
- it is assumed that the number of bits in an `uint8_t` is 8 and that **S * 8** is divisible by **b**

Examples:

- b = 4, array = `0xA0 0x39 0x04 0x30`- correct answer is 3
- b = 1, array = `0xFF 0x1F 0xF8` - correct answer is 6
- b = 16, array = `0x05 0x16 0x32 0x00` - correct answer is 0

What i'm currently doing is I "unpack" the bits into bytes and then memcmp the subsequences with a zero buffer, but it seems to me there should be a faster way of doing this.

Comment: Good question, just for completeness: what's the endianness? Is the answer 1 for `b = 4` and `array = [0xFC 0x3F]`? Or is it for `array = [0x3F 0xFC]`?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: Good catch. I'm assumming little endian. For `b = 4` and either of those arrays the answer is `0` since there is no 4bit subsequence that is all zeroes. The subsequences are non-overlapping so its comparing bits 0-3, 4-7 etc.

Comment: But there's a non-overlapping 4-bit subsequence in `1111110000111111` (i.e. `0xFC3F`). -> non-overlapping means that the b-bit subsequences are not overlapping each other, not that you cannot overlap multiple bytes (otherwise how would you do >8-bit subsequences?)

Comment: I'm looking for these subsequences in a byte array. So if i have a 8 bytes, it means its 64 bits. Byte 0 is bits 0-7, byte 1 is bits 8-15 etc. I don't understand the example you gave. There are 16 bits, so if b=4, the first subsequence is 1111, second 1100, third 0011 and fourth 1111, none of which are zero, so the answer is 0.

Comment: You should specify that in your question because that's a different problem than if you consider non-overlapping zero sequences at any bit-offset.

Comment: What is the use of this? Are you sure this is exactly what you want? :)

Comment: @wilx maybe counting empty chunks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bit-twiddling similar to the well-known method for detecting a null byte in a string. For example for b=4, you can read a 32-bit word `x` and do

```
__builtin_popcount((x - 0x11111111) & (~x & 0x88888888))
```

Here, `x - 0x11111111` produces a value where the high bit of each 4-bit group is 1 if the 4-bit group is zero or it was already set; the second part discards those where it was already set, and then you just count the bits remaining.

Answer (score 1):

For the additional constraint of only considering sequences starting at `b` bit offsets there's a very simple solution (also endianness is not an issue here, since you're only considering whole chunks of zeroes):

```
size_t countZeroChunks(const uint8_t* bytes, size_t nbytes, uint8_t b) {
    assert(b == 2 || b == 4 || b == 8 || b == 16 || b == 32);
    size_t count = 0;
    if(b <= 8) {
        // chunks fit inside a byte
        for(size_t i = 0; i < nbytes; ++i) {
            uint8_t byte = *bytes++;
            for(uint8_t offset = 0; offset < 8; offset += b) {
                // collect bits in chunk
                // e.g. for b=2 at offset=2
                // yyyyxxyy >> 2 -> 00yyyyxx
                // 00yyyyxx << 6 -> xx000000
                uint8_t chunk = (byte >> offset) << ((8 - offset) % 8);
                if(chunk == 0)
                    ++count;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // chunks span multiple bytes
        size_t nchunks = nbytes * 8 / b;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < nchunks; ++i) {
            // collect chunk from bytes
            uint32_t chunk = 0;
            for(size_t k = 0, bytesPerChunk = b / 8; k < bytesPerChunk; ++k)
                chunk |= (uint32_t)(*bytes++) << (k * 8);
            if(chunk == 0)
                ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```